# Countably generated modules with local endomorphism rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules

I have to give a lecture for undergraduate students about a theorem by Crawley-Jonsson-Warfield which states that *if a module $M$ is a direct sum of countably generated modules, each with local endomorphism ring, then so is every direct summand of $M$* .

The proof of this theorem (or at least the one I'm focusing on) uses the following theorem (first proved by Kaplansky and then extended by C. Walker to this form):

*Let $c$ be an infinite cardinal. If a module $M$ is a direct sum of $c$-generated submodules, then so is every direct summand of $M$* .

I would like to have some more bibliography from which to read these theorems (and others that might be related), since so far I've only found them in Anderson and Fuller's "Rings and Categories of Modules" and in Rotman's "Introduction to Homological Algebra".

Any suggestions on reading material would be very much appreciated!